# matplotlib contour plot colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I have two different contour plots with the same levels, how can I get the color progression in the colorbar/plot to match?

**Contour Plot 1 (see colorbar range 0 to 0.005):**
[image]

**Contour Plot 2 (color range 0 to 0.005 is different color):**
[image]
How can I get them to match?
Thanks

```
level = np.arange(0,0.05,0.005) 
levels =np.append([pmin],level)
plt.contourf(X,Y,Z,levels)
plt.colorbar()
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal','box')
plt.gca().set_xlim(min(XI),max(XI))
plt.gca().set_ylim(min(YI),max(YI))
plt.show()
```

Comment: It'd be good if you show the relevant code.

Comment: Well the data that forms the plot is obviously different... You can weight the max/min values in each data set and then use that weighted scale as your colour range as opposed to using fixed values.

Comment: See [mcve]. . .

Comment: Adam : Yes the data is different but the contour levels are fixed - so shouldn't anything between 0 to 0.005 be the same color in the "colorbar" (not the actual plot)

Comment: The code is not runnable, so I cannot provide a full answer; but the problem is that while you are fixing the levels themselves, you do not fix the norm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalizing as suggested fixed the problem.

https://matplotlib.org/users/colormapnorms.html